# How can I get the Text value of input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

How can I get the value of the textbox?

```
<input class="num1" type="text" val=""><br>
<button class="show">Click</button>
```

this is my Js code:

```
var value = $('.num1').text();
$('.Click').click(function(){
    $('<'p>').text(value);   
});
```

when I clicked the "click" button I want to show in a paragraph the text that I'd input to the textbox.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.val()` for form elements to retrieve or set its value. Also, care with typo when you set the paragraph text.

```
var value = $('.num1').val();
$('.show').on('click', function(){
    $('p').text(value);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code there is an error: if you want to catch the click event you should use the class of the button. Another error in your code is about the single quotes you use to insert value into the `<p>`. And remember, is `$('p')`, not `$('<p>')`.

The code should look like that:

```
$('.show').click(function(){
    $('p').text(value);   
});
```

You can use this code:

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){

        $("form").on("submit", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            var text = $(".num1").val();

            $("#outputText").text(text);
        })

    });
```

Your HTML should be something like that:

**HTML**

```
 <form>
        <input class="num1" type="text" val="">
        <button class="show">Click</button>
</form>

<p id="outputText"></p>
```

Note that in this case is really important to stop the default event behavior using [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

If you are not using a form the previous code became something like that:

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){

            $(".show").on("click", function(event){

                var text = $(".num1").val();

                $("#outputText").text(text);
            })

        });
```

**HTML**

```
    <input class="num1" type="text" val=""> 
    <button class="show">Click</button>

    <p id="outputText">

    </p>
```

The `outputText` div is a div I've created to show the text.

I've prepared [jsfiddle1](https://jsfiddle.net/sw47uehy/), [jsfiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/sw47uehy/1/) you can use to see the code in action, I hope it helps ;-)

Answer (score 2):

That would be

```
var value = $('.num1').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.val()` not `.text()`

```
 $(".show").click(function(){
      var value=  $(".num1").val();
   $(".para").text(value)

    });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wow8q7we/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `val()` operator on the input to get the value, and then you could use the following code:

Html:

```
<input class="num1" type="text">
<button class="show">Click</button>
<p class="output"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.output').html($('.num1').val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.show').click(function () {
    var value = $('.num1').val();
    $('p').text(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="num1" type="text" val=""></input>
<button class="show">Click</button>
<p></p>
```

There are type mistakes

1. `var value = $('.num1').val();` should be in `click` method.
2. Use `val()` instead of `.text()` to get the input value.